# After using MultiDex in Android Studio, 2 Menus in Navigation are not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-relativelayout, android-multidex

I am using Audacity Template in Android Studio, 
after MultiDex, About Us and Methodology are getting some error, and in Both the Layout (Relative and Linear Both Layout are used in each one)

I think some class or Function has disabled after using multiDex Application in Android Studio

Comment: have you used multiDex true in gradle file

Comment: clean your project and restart, your problem may get solved :)